# Origin and first uses of $\ell_p$ norms?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ho.history-overview

When exactly were $\ell_p$ norms first defined and used?

(Here is what I know, or think I know: Lebesgue and/or Riesz had something to do with them, but in some sense they go back to Minkowski, since Minkowski's inequality is (in essence) the statement that an $\ell_p$ norm is a norm.)

Here is what is really my main question: how were $\ell_p$ norms ($p\geq 1$ arbitrary) first used? What was their motivation? It is clear that $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$ and $\ell_\infty$ norms are very natural, and their use long predates the formal definition of "form". The $\ell_4$ norm also pops up on its own sometimes. In contrast, $\ell_p$ norms for other $p$ seem to arise most often in the course of a proof, as a tool, when one needs some notion of "size" that falls between an $\ell_1$ and an $\ell_2$ norm (for example). Did the first uses of $\ell_p$ norms fit this framework? Can you think of some interesting (and preferably early) instances that do not obey this pattern?

Comment: I don't really know the answer, but Section 4.4 of Pietsch's book *History of Banach spaces and linear operators* may be of interest. The references cited in Subsection 4.4.6 seem to be amongst the oldest cited in that section of Pietsch's book.

Comment: In terms of when they were first considered as 'norms', the following remark from p.3 of Pietsch's book may be noteworthy: *"Note that the concept of a norm was not yet in use, though Riesz proved Minkowski's inequality."*

Comment: Explicit considerations of p-norm distances for $p=3$, $p=4$ or $p=5$ emerge quite naturally in the field of data clustering. Unfortunately, I don’t know any early paper on this but it seems that such issues had to be considered almost from the beginning of the field. This paper can be seen as a modern example of such considerations: http://gracehopper.org/2004/Proceedings/PDF/ni_Vadapalli.pdf

Comment: This also doesn't answer your question, but you may be interested to know there are results that characterize $\ell_p$ in natural ways.  See http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/03/characterizing_the_pnorms.html

Comment: Plancherel formulas for Fourier series are a canonical example of the use of the $\ell_2$-norm. It would be interesting where this was first of observed and whether it predates the reference in the other answers.

Comment: @MarcPalm: The $\ell_2$ Plancherel formula for Fourier series is usually attributed to Parseval (1806), here: http://books.google.com/books?id=ehDR3viTXNoC&pg=PA638

Comment: I don't really see why talk of the Plancherel formula has any relevance to HAH's question "how were $\ell^p$ norms ($p\geq 1$ arbitrary) first used?" - but then perhaps I am being overly literal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Toeplitz in his [review](http://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?44.0401.01) of Riesz [[1913](http://archive.org/stream/lessystmesdq00riesuoft)] laments the lack of explicit motivation in generalizing from $\ell_2$ to $\ell_p$:

> The considerations of the 3rd Chapter require not the convergence of the sum of squares of the unknowns, but the more general convergence of $\sum|x_a|^p$, where $1<p<\infty$ (even the limiting cases $p = 1$, $p = \infty$ are discussed), ***a generalization on which the author seems to place considerable value, but whose deeper analytic significance he doesn't further motivate***.

But isn't the motivation simply that this increases the chances for a system $\sum a_{ik}x_k=c_i$ to have a solution? Namely (if $p>2$ say) we are allowed to look for solutions in the wider space $\ell_p$ — but the price to pay is that we must know that each "row" $a_{i\,\cdot}$ is in $\ell_q$ where $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$. That seems to be the point of the theorem that Riesz [1913, p. 47] attributes to Landau [[1907](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002501031)]:

> *If $\sum a_kx_k$ converges for all $x\in\ell_p$, then $a\in\ell_q$* (*and* $|\sum a_kx_k|\leqslant\|a\|_q\|x\|_p$).$(*)$

This, in retrospect, is essentially the proof that $\ell_p$ has dual $\ell_q$, and I would say it qualifies as a use of $\ell_p$ norms predating Riesz. But as to who first *used* this to solve a concrete problem...? I don't know.

Another pre-Riesz $\ell_p$ result is the Hausdorff-Young inequalities for Fourier series $f(e^{i\theta})=\sum c_ne^{in\theta}$, proved by Young in [[1912a](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k31089/f35.image)] (resp. [[1912b](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k31089/f498.image)]) for $q\in 2\mathbf Z$ and later by Hausdorff in general:

> *If $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$ and $1<p\leqslant 2$, then* $\|c\|_q\leqslant\|f\|_p$ (*resp.* $\|f\|_q\leqslant\|c\|_p$).

**More secondary sources** — in addition to the Dieudonné and Pietsch texts cited by András:

- Riesz [1913, p. 45] attributes the Minkowski inequality to Minkowski [[1907, p. 95](http://archive.org/stream/diophantischeapp00minkuoft#page/95)], but there is no such thing there. According to [this paper](http://pure.ltu.se/portal/en/publications/why-hoelders-inequality-should-be-called-rogers-inequality%2800c8b880-a576-11db-9811-000ea68e967b%29.html) the correct reference is Minkowski [[1896, p. 116](http://archive.org/stream/geometriederzahl00minkrich#page/n133)].
- [*Encyklopädie der math. Wiss.*, Vol. II.3.2](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/toc/?PPN=PPN360506542) (1927) reports on both Riesz's $\ell_p$ theory with forerunners Hölder and Landau (p. 1445, no mention of Minkowski), and on Hausdorff-Young (pp. 1211-1212).
- A more recent survey: [*The Hausdorff-Young theorems of Fourier analysis and their impact*](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/en/dms/img/?PPN=PPN375375147_0001&DMDID=dmdlog10) (1994).
- According to [this paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2347705), Hölder's inequality $(*)$ goes back to Grolous (1875) and Besso (1879).

Yet again, none of these references really address the motivation for generalizing from $\ell_2$ to $\ell_p$. Maybe it was a case of "because we can..."?

Comment: Hausdorff-Young and duality make general $p\ne 2$ of interest if you are already interested in *some* $p\ne 2$...

Comment: Exactly. And so I feel that I have failed to find any early ***use*** of $\ell_p$ norms in the sense you seem to want: an application to *something else*. It might help if you gave (not necessarily early) examples of what *you* consider significant uses or applications: then one could try to trace back their history.

Comment: I believe Riesz's reference to page 95 of Minkowski is a misprint for page 85 where Minkowski shows that convexity of a solid containing the origin is equivalent to homogeneity and the triangle inequality of its associated gauge functional (equations (37), (39)). The convexity of the two-dimensional $\ell_p$-balls is proved on page 48, where there is the familiar picture of the nested $\ell_p$ unit balls in the plane.

Answer (score 9):

[Dieudonné](http://books.google.hu/books/about/History_of_Functional_Analysis.html?id=mg7r4acKgq0C&redir_esc=y) and [Pietsch](http://books.google.hu/books/about/History_of_Banach_Spaces_and_Linear_Oper.html?id=MMorKHumdZAC&redir_esc=y) both believe that Frederic Riesz was the one to introduce the spaces $l^p$ in his monograph

"[Les systèmes d'équations linéaires à une infinité d'inconnues](http://archive.org/details/lessystmesdq00riesuoft)", 1913.

This seems to be available online, which is good because unfortunately I cannot read French very well...

It seems that indeed, he develops here the theory of $l^p$-spaces, much later than the spaces $L^p$, which were considered by him in

"[Untersuchungen über Systeme integrierbarer Funktionen](http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01457637)" in 1909.

In the first two chapters of his monograph, Riesz mentions motivations for his work: infinite systems of equations, infinite determinants, theorems of Landau and Pringsheim. Someone who can read better French could expand my list...